# How do I check the index of a an element in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list

```
list = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
```

How do I do:

list.index('hh') ...and returns 1?

Then, how do I sort it by the 25, 5, 4?

What if I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
list2 = [('ja',40), ('hgh',88), ('hh', 2)]
```

how do I do a for each?

```
for item in l1:
    if item[0] in l2[0 of the tuple]:
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question from "What if I have 2 lists..." - What output do you expect?

Comment: It's ok, I got it. Your answer solves it. thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use keywords as variable names. It can lead to confusing bugs.

Comment: @Mark your point is well taken, but `list` is *not* a keyword. It is an identifier which has been assigned a value by the standard library.

Comment: Don't use identifiers which have been assigned values by the standard library as variable names. It can lead to confusing bugs. Don't use identifiers which shadow built-in functions as variable names. It can lead to confusing bugs.

Comment: With three questions of a n00b nature on a Sunday afternoon, I'm guessing this is homework.  Please tag homework clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the finding

```
>>> L = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
>>> [ i for i,l in enumerate(L) if l[0] == 'hh' ][0]
1
```

You need to decide what to do if it is found multiple times or not at all - the above will throw `IndexError` if not found and return the first if it is found multiple times.

For the sorting

```
>>> L = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x: x[1])
[('ba', 4), ('hh', 5), ('gg', 25)]
```

Answer (score 5):

First of, don't use `list` as the name for a variable, as it shadows the built-in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#list) function.

1. You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#enumerate) to pair up list elements and their index:

   ```
   >>> l = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
   >>> [i for i, e in enumerate(l) if e[0] == 'hh']
   [1]
   ```
2. For sorting you can use a `lambda` expression as shown by others, or you can pass an [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the `key` argument to [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#sorted):

   ```
   >>> from operator import itemgetter
   >>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
   [('ba', 4), ('hh', 5), ('gg', 25)]
   ```
3. In-place sorting is also possible, using the [`sort`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method on lists:

   ```
   >>> l.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think Nick's sorting answer is good, but his find method unnecessarily iterates over the entire list, even after it has found a match. With a small change it can be fixed to stop iterating as soon as it finds the first element:

```
index = (i for i,l in enumerate(l) if l[0] == 'aa').next()
```

Or in Python 3:

```
index = next(i for i,l in enumerate(l) if l[0] == 'aa')
```

Comment: Note that for Python 3 this should be `next(...)` instead of `(...).next()`.

Comment: `next()` throws `StopIteration` if `'aa'` is not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

to sort the list u can use a custom sort method some thing like this

```
x = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]

def sortMethod(x,y):
    if x[1] < y[1]:return 1
    elif x[1] > y[1]:return -1
    else: return 0


print x         #unsorted
x.sort(sortMethod)
print x         #sorted
```

Comment: This sort method is much slower than the one shown by Nick Craig-Wood.

Comment: No downvoting - but this is not pythonic. See Nick's answer for the *right* way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

you can also have your list in dictionary form

```
list1 = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
dict1 = dict(list1)

print dict1['hh']
5
```

dicts are faster then list if you need to search like that.

btw, overriding built-in type `list` to variables are not good idea `list = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]`.

Comment: just a question .. isn't converting the list to dict will take time especially if it was a big list ?

Comment: of coz, but if he need to search multiple times, looping each items in list are not good for item retriving, dont you think so? building dict is normally one time, but for searching its very fast.

Answer (score 1):

For the sort, you should use itemgetter

```
>>> import operator
>>> L = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
>>> sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[('ba', 4), ('hh', 5), ('gg', 25)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import imap

def find(iterable, item, key=None):
    """Find `item` in `iterable`.

    Return index of the found item or ``-1`` if there is none.

    Apply `key` function to items before comparison with
    `item`. ``key=None`` means an identity function.
    """
    it = iter(iterable) if key is None else imap(key, iterable)
    for i, e in enumerate(it):
        if e == item:
            return i
    return -1
```

Example:

```
L = [('ba', 4), ('hh', 5), ('gg', 25)]
print find(L, 'hh', key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last question, convert list2 into a set:

```
>>> list1 = [('ba',4), ('hh',5), ('gg', 25)]
>>> list2 = [('ja',40), ('hgh',88), ('hh', 2)]
>>> 
>>> wanted = set(a for (a,b) in list2)
>>> for x in list1:
...     if x[0] in wanted:
...         print x
... 
('hh', 5)
```